# Java Array with if else condition

Tags: java, arrays

I have 4 different sets of logic to set different multiple values to an array.
I have tried this:

```
int[] numbers;

if(a) { numbers = {11, 22, 33, 44, -11, -22, 33, 44}; }

if(b) { numbers = {66, 33, 11, 00, 11, 22, 33, 44}; }

if(c) { numbers = {-11, -22, 33, 44, 66, 33, 11, 00}; }
```

I found many answers by using index of the array one by one value set, but is there any effective easy way to set like above?

Comment: So, what's the issue with what you're doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, use `else if` after the first if instead to be able to exit early and avoid later logic overwriting the previous set value. Second, you need to prepend `new int[]` as you are not initializing it in the declaration.

```
if(a) { numbers = new int[]{11, 22, 33, 44, -11, -22, 33, 44}; }
else if(b) { numbers = new int[]{66, 33, 11, 00, 11, 22, 33, 44}; }
else if(c) { numbers = new int[]{-11, -22, 33, 44, 66, 33, 11, 00}; }
else {
    //default value, e.g.
    numbers = new int[8];
}
```

You can also use the ternary operator to initialize in the declaration so there is no need to prepend `new int[]`, but note that it may be less readable.

```
int[] numbers = a ? {11, 22, 33, 44, -11, -22, 33, 44} : 
       b ? {66, 33, 11, 00, 11, 22, 33, 44} :
       c ? {-11, -22, 33, 44, 66, 33, 11, 00} :
       /*default value*/ new int[8];
```

Answer (score 2):

A if-else-if expression:

```
int[] numbers =
    a ? {11, 22, 33, 44, -11, -22, 33, 44}
    : b ? {66, 33, 11, 00, 11, 22, 33, 44}
    : {-11, -22, 33, 44, 66, 33, 11, 00};
```